# Is GCP Pub/Sub supported by VPC Service Control?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-networking

Google APIs and Services that are supported by VPC Service Controls based on Supported products and limitations available [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products) includes Pub/Sub, Cloud Monitoring and Cloud Logging.

However a related documentation available here about configuring Private Google Access for on-premises hosts available [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access-hybrid) has Pub/Sub, Monitoring and Logging listed under *Reached using Private Google Access* ***but not secured by VPC Service Controls***.

I am confused reading this. Can Pub/Sub access (as well as Monitoring and Logging) be secured by VPC Service Controls or not?

**Edit**
Uploaded image[image] of new VPC Service Control creation screen that allows PubSub to be selected as one of the services to be restricted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing both documents, I can see that, as you commented, Pub/Sub is a Supported  VPC SC product. However, the combination of these 3 products: Private Google Access + VPC SC + Pub/Sub will not work. Therefore you can secure these products (Pub/Sub, Monitoring and Logging) by using VPC Service Controls without using Private Google Access (service that allow on-premises hosts to reach the Google APIS without using public IPS)

Comment: Thank you. I do need PubSub and use it from outside GCP. From the same documentation, I guess there is an option to use Private Google Access from On-premises without VPC Service Controls. My guess is Private Google Access (from On-premise) will enable accessing PubSub over a VPN/InterConnect without going through internet. VPC Service Controls would have made it more secure. Interestingly, PubSub is listed under the services to be restricted when a new VPC Service Control is created. Have added a screenshot as well. Hope I can get a word from GCP support on this.

Comment: Hello, I've confirmed that is not possible to use Private Google Access with VPC Service Control and Pub/SuB: please see the following Feature Request from Google Cloud Platform: https://issuetracker.google.com/135244419. However, is possible that this feature will be implemented in the future. I would suggest you to ‘star’ it to ensure that you receive updates about it [1]

Comment: [1] https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue

Comment: Thank you again Ricardo. I will vote up for the feature request. I am hoping that it's possible to use Private Google Access for PubSub WITHOUT VPC Service Control. Would it be possible to confirm?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use Private Google Access for PubSub WITHOUT VPC Service Control. As described on this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#pga Supported services
Private Google Access permits access to Cloud and Developer APIs and most Google Cloud services, except for the following services:

App Engine Memcache
Filestore
Memorystore
Cloud SQL